# Azure: Can't find TableStorageDataServiceEntity class

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

I've been working my way through this [tutorial](http://www.robbagby.com/azure/azure-application-part-2-access-azure-table-storage/comment-page-1/#comment-412). I got stuck when it asked me to make a class that inherits from `TableStorageDataServiceContext`. I can't seem to find the .dll or namespace or whatever.

`DataServiceContext` works fine. That tutorial is a bit old. Has the class been moved or no longer exists or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial that you're following is from when Azure was only in CTP, some of the class names changed when it came out of CTP (they've been stable since then).  The class I think this is now meant to refer to is `TableServiceContext`.

It is in the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll` which is probably installed in `C:\Program Files\Windows Azure SDK\v1.2\ref` if you didn't change any of the settings while [installing the SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=21910585-8693-4185-826e-e658535940aa&displaylang=en).

It might be worth finding a [more up to date tutorial](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=413E88F8-5966-4A83-B309-53B7B77EDF78&displaylang=en) though, I'm not sure what other minor differences there might be.

Comment: Yeah, I've done some stuff from that training kit, but it wasn't for SL. Perhaps I'll have to go back and do that.